# Calculate propensity-scores within strata

Tags: r, propensity-score-matching

Assume the following data:

```
library(cobalt)
library(dplyr)

set.seed(123)

# Extending lalonde data by `group` variable:
lalonde <- cbind(lalonde,
                 group = sample(c("A", "B", "AB"), size = 614, replace = TRUE))

# Creating variable `set` for AB group:
lalonde$set[lalonde$group == "AB"] <- sample(c(5, 10, 15, 3), sum(lalonde$group == "AB"), replace = TRUE)

# Filling 'set' column for `group` 'A' and 'B':
prob_80 <- sample(c(0, 1), nrow(lalonde), replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.8, 0.2))
lalonde$set[(lalonde$group == "A" | lalonde$group == "B") & prob_80 == 1] <- sample(c(5, 10, 15, 3), sum((lalonde$group == "A" | lalonde$group == "B") & prob_80 == 1), replace = TRUE)
lalonde$set[(lalonde$group == "A" | lalonde$group == "B") & is.na(lalonde$set)] <- sample(1:100, sum((lalonde$group == "A" | lalonde$group == "B") & is.na(lalonde$set)), replace = TRUE)
```

Now we have a `group` variable containing either `A`, `B`, `AB` and a variable named `set`.

Now I want to fit a logistic PS model stratified by the `set` values of `group == "AB"`, predicting being in group `AB`.

First I would pull the distinct values of `set`, being in `group == AB`.

```
unique_set_values <- unique(lalonde[lalonde$group == "AB", "set"])  %>% 
  print()
```

which are:

```
+   print()
[1]  5 15 10  3
```

I use those to get all observations which belong to one of the `set` values:

```
filtered_data <- lalonde %>% 
  filter(set %in% unique_set_values)
```

Then I split the data and replace `AB` with `1`, else `0`:

```
# For AB and A:
AB_A <- filtered_data %>% 
  filter(group %in% c("AB", "A")) %>%
  mutate(group = ifelse(group == "AB", 1, 0)) 

# For AB and B:
AB_B <- filtered_data %>% 
  filter(group %in% c("AB", "B")) %>%
  mutate(group = ifelse(group == "AB", 1, 0))
```

Now I can calculate the stratified PS for `AB` and `A` as well as `AB` and `B`:

```
# Creating a formula:
formula <- group ~ age + educ + race + married + nodegree + re74 + re75 + re78
```

But how to calculate the PS stratified by `set` in such scenario?

I tried:

```
AB_A_PS <- AB_A %>%
  group_by(set) %>%
  mutate(pscore = glm(formula, data = ., family = binomial(link = "logit"))$fitted.values)
```

but all I get is an error:

```
Error in `mutate()`:
ℹ In argument: `pscore = predict(glm(formula, data = ., family = binomial(link = "logit")))`.
ℹ In group 1: `set = 3`.
Caused by error:
! `pscore` must be size 66 or 1, not 238.
```

So, obviously, it does not work.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing the whole grouped data frame to `glm` for each group within the data frame, hence the error. Instead, you can pass the subset of the data frame that contains only the rows in the current group:

```r
AB_A %>%
  group_by(set) %>%
  mutate(pscore = glm(formula, data = .[cur_group_rows(),], 
                    family = binomial(link = "logit"))$fitted.values)
#> # A tibble: 238 x 12
#> # Groups:   set [4]
#>    treat   age  educ race   married nodegree  re74  re75   re78 group   set pscore
#>    <int> <int> <int> <fct>    <int>    <int> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
#>  1     1    37    11 black        1        1     0     0  9930.     1     5  0.706
#>  2     1    22     9 hispan       0        1     0     0  3596.     1    15  0.942
#>  3     1    30    12 black        0        0     0     0 24909.     1    15  0.993
#>  4     1    33     8 black        0        1     0     0   290.     1    15  0.977
#>  5     1    22    16 black        0        0     0     0  2164.     1    15  0.835
#>  6     1    17     7 black        0        1     0     0  3024.     1    15  0.908
#>  7     1    27    13 black        0        0     0     0 14582.     1    10  1    
#>  8     1    23    10 black        0        1     0     0  7693.     1    15  0.939
#>  9     1    26    12 black        0        0     0     0 10747.     0     3  0.809
#> 10     1    38     9 white        0        1     0     0  6409.     1    10  1    
#> # i 228 more rows
#> # i Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```